# gnuplot: xtics not shown on X-axis

Tags: linux, graph, gnuplot, gnu

I am trying to populate graph with some fixed values on X-axis and corresponding values on Y-axis. With my below script, no values are labelled on X-axis and value on Y-axis are labelled with powers.

1. How to make xtics data(1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000) appear on X-axis ?
2. How to get rid of powers on Y-axis ? (Example : I want 4000000 on Y-axis instead of 4x10^6

   ```
   set xrange [0:]
   set output "macs.png"
   set ylabel "Flows/sec"
   set xlabel  "MACS per Switch"
   set grid
   set xtics (1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000)
   set style line 2 lt 1 lw 2 pt 1 linecolor 1
   plot "macs.data" using :1 with linespoints linestyle 0 title "Floodlight" // Using ":1" as X-axis data is supplied in xtics
   ```

Here is my data file :

```
# Not Supplying X-axis data here as it is supplied through xtics
400
60000
700000
800000
900000
```

I want my populated graph with only one line to looks like this  :[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have supply x and y value for each point. Fortunately, gnuplot supports some special column numbers like column 0, which is a counter of valid data sets, i.e. here a line number ignoring comments. It starts at zero.

Next, your x-axis uses a log scale, so you should do it, too. The formula to convert line number to correct x-value is  10<sup>(colum_0) + 3</sup>. which translates to `10**($0+3)` in gnuplot.

Here is the code:

```
# Logarithmic scale for x axis
set log x


# get rid of scientific formatting of numbers,
# plain format also for large numbers
set format x "%.0f"

# If you don't like the small ticks between the large ones
set mxtics 1

# put the key (legend) outside, right of the plot area, 
# vertically centered (as in your picture)
set key outside right center


# only horizontal grid lines
set grid y   


plot "macs.data" using (10**($0+3)):1 title "foo" with linespoints
```

And here the result:

[image]

---

**Alternative:**

Your approach plots the data as if it were given like

```
0   400
1  60000
2 700000
3 800000
4 900000
```

In this case, you need to label the x-axis on your own, the correct syntax is

```
set xtics("1000" 0, "10000" 1, "100000" 2, "1000000" 3, "10000000" 4)
```

This will not draw any automatic labels, but it will put e.g. your string `10000` at x=1

Comment: If I set the xtics using set xtics("1000" 0, "10000" 1, "100000" 2, "1000000" 3, "10000000" 4), Do I need to specify column number for X-axis in plot ? (Example :  _plot "macs.data" using :2 title "foo" with linespoints_ Is it fine ? )

Comment: if you don't give a number, gnuplot uses the default. So `using :2` should be an equivalent to `using 1:2`. But your data has only one column, so you should use `using 0:1`. As said, the `0` is a special column.